# Spread items evenly along the x axis

Tags: math, godot, gdscript

I am writing game code for blackjack to fan the players cards in their hand. This uses an array to tween the items by setting their vector2 position along the `x` axis. I am having issues with the math to evenly distribute the vectors on both sides of the `y` axis. You start with two cards, and then are dealt a card every turn, so the array populates as such:

```
[ item1, item2 ]
// Card dealt
[ item1, item2, item3 ]
// Card dealt
[ item1, item2, item3, item4 ]
// Card dealt
[ item1, item2, item3, item4, item5 ]
```

So I created a function called `_spread_cards` and it looks like the below code. For my final result I would like the cards spread evenly along the `x` axis where the middle card (if there is one) is located at `(0,0)` of the parent item. If there isn't a parent they should be spread 20 from the parent item.

```py
func _spread_cards() -> void:
    var card_count = cards.size()
    var cards_to_left = floor(card_count / 2)
    var has_middle = card_count % 2 == 1
    var deck_x = global_position.x
    var deck_y = global_position.y
    var i = 0
    var spread = 20

    for card in cards:
        var is_middle = true if has_middle and i == cards_to_left else false
        var is_left = true if not is_middle and i < cards_to_left else false
        var is_right = true if not is_middle and i >= cards_to_left else false

        if is_middle:
            card.move_to(Vector2(deck_x, deck_y), 0.1)
            print('middle: ' + String(deck_x))
        elif is_left:
            print('left: ' + String(deck_x - (spread * (i + 1))))
            card.move_to(Vector2(deck_x - (spread * (i + 1)), deck_y), 0.1)
        elif is_right:
            card.move_to(Vector2(deck_x + (spread * (i + 1 - cards_to_left)), deck_y), 0.1)
            print('right: ' + String(deck_x + (spread * (i + 1 - cards_to_left))))
        i += 1
```

That results in the following, where the cards are not spaced out correctly. It seems as if it is more the right hand side. Here is the result of the above code:

[image]

Comment: Removed Python tag and added GDScript tag.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my ideoa as to how you can achieve this with [linspace()](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiettKyr_HpAhWuUt8KHWbHCVwQFjAAegQIAxAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdocs.scipy.org%2Fdoc%2Fnumpy%2Freference%2Fgenerated%2Fnumpy.linspace.html&usg=AOvVaw2fvqtUXD7HItalMyuIWpSH):

```
import numpy as np

cards = [card1,card2,card3]
num_of_cards = len(cards) # Number of cards currently

spread = np.linspace(-50,50,num=numr_of_cards) # Assuming the cards must stay in the boundaries of -50 and 50 for the x cordinate

for card,x in zip(cards,spread):
    card.x = x
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: OP is actually using GDScript, not Python. They can't use Numpy here.